# how to limit navbar-fixed to container width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first Twitter Bootstrap project.

Using Twitter Bootstrap, it doesn't seem to matter, if I use container-fluid or just container for my fixed navbar at top. Once it gets past about 980 px is suddenly shoots out to the full width of the browser. I have observed it with both Firefox and IE.

Any ideas?

My code below:

in head:

```
<link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

in body:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<a class="brand" href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i></a>
<a class="brand" href="#">Time Machine: Lawrence, Kansas</a>
<ul class="nav pull-right">
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>  
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <a class="btn btn-inverse" href="#"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i> Buildings</a>
  <a class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i> Blocks</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i> Buildings test out long string</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-search"></i> Businesses</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="i"></i> Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="btn btn-inverse" href="#"><i class="icon-repeat icon-white"></i></a>
</div>
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>  
</ul> <!-- nav class -->

</div> <!-- navbar-inner -->
</div> <!-- navbar navbar-fixed-top -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `bootstrap-responsive.css`. This enables the responsive features that will resize all DIVs to 100% once the browser is resized to less than 979px.

```
<link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

If you want to keep the responsive features, you can use a CSS @media query to change CSS styles for just the navbar. You'd put this in another CSS file (or  container) and include it after the bootstrap-responsive..

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {

    .navbar { ... }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Skelly . Since I like the responsive features in general (my first attempt at a web app that should also work as a web presence for desktop browsers), I hate to lose that so I took the approach of adding my own .css to override the bootstrap and bootstrap responsive but I can't see where the navbar is going "auto" - that it's going to 100% *after* the browser increases past around 980 px - this after copying and pasting the entire '@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)' section of bootstrap-responsive and changing it to '@media (min-width: 979px) {'

It seems like

Comment: I think I misunderstood this on multiple levels. The problem is in limiting the navbar from going to 100% browser width once the browser portal exceeds approx 980 px (fluid responsive behavior, I think). 

But adding CSS like the above (which seems like it should be min-width and not max-width since the area I'm trying to exert control over is when 980 is exceeded.  @Skelly